# Tabbing through links that are hidden on webpage (accessibility issue)

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I have a web page with 3 links.  1 of the links is hidden by a parent div that has display:none.  When I hover over another div however, the hidden div will be shown thereby revealing the link.  How can I tab through all 3 links and get link 3 to display automatically when i tab to it?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Skype Home</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   a,.hoverMe{
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#CCC;
   }
   .hoverMe{
    background-color:pink;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
   }
   .hiddenDiv{
    visibility:hidden;
   }
   .hiddenDiv.shown{
    visibility:visible;
   }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(
   function(){
    $(".hoverMe").hover(
     function(){
      $(".hiddenDiv").addClass("shown");
     },
     function(){
      $(".hiddenDiv").removeClass("shown");
     }
    )
   }
  );
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#2">Link 2</a>
  <div class="hoverMe">hover me to open Link 3</div>
  <div class="hiddenDiv">
   <a href="#3">Link 3</a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seeing your markup and CSS will help with answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript.

Add an onfocus and onblur handler to the anchor that toggle a class on the parent div. Edit your stylesheet to reveal it when the class is set.

Also add a flag to indicate JS is present, e.g.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.className += " js";
</script>
```

… and protect the rule that hides the div in the first place with `body.js` followed by a descendent selector (so non-JS users will still be able to access the content).

Comment: display: none content is out of the tab order? I have to confess to not having tested it. In that you you would also have to switch from `display: none` to `position: absolute; left: -1000px;` or similar.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in ie6 at least when you put rtl as the dir attribute for html, a huge horizontal scrollbar will appear due to the negative offset of the hidden div.  Anyway to fix this?

Comment: I fixed this negative scroll bar issue with rtl, trick was to put overflow hidden on the element.